# remove event listener on a input in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I an attaching event listeners in input box by using ID. so its working fine but I want to remove event listeners its will not work for me.

```
document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener("keyup", function({
    console.log(document.getElementById("myInput").value);
});


  document.getElementById("myInput").removeEventListener("keyup",function() {

});
```

Comment: a named function will  help you here .. !

Answer (score 5):

The second argument needs to be the event listener you want to remove (so you need to keep a reference to that function around instead of putting a function expression directly as the argument to `addEventListener`).

You're passing it a brand new function. It doesn't get removed, because that function wasn't listening in the first place.

```
var in = document.getElementById("myInput");

function myListener (event) {
    console.log(in.value);
}

in.addEventListener("keyup", myListener);
in.removeEventListener("keyup", myListener);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try that

```
var fn = function({
    console.log(document.getElementById("myInput").value);
}

document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener("keyup", fn);
document.getElementById("myInput").removeEventListener("keyup", fn);
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> var body =
>         document.querySelector('body'),
>     clickTarget =
>         document.getElementById('click-target'),
>     mouseOverTarget =
>         document.getElementById('mouse-over-target'),
>     toggle = false;
>
> function makeBackgroundYellow() {
>     'use strict';
>
>     if (toggle) {
>         body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
>     } else {
>         body.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
>     }
>
>     toggle = !toggle;
> }
>
> clickTarget.addEventListener('click',
>     makeBackgroundYellow,
>     false
> );
>
> mouseOverTarget.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
>     'use strict';
>
>     clickTarget.removeEventListener('click',
>         makeBackgroundYellow,
>         false
>     );
> });
>
>
> target.removeEventListener(type, listener[, options]);
> target.removeEventListener(type, listener[, useCapture]);
> ```

the second argument is the eventlistener you want to remove, see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

Comment: Your answer is good, but a little big for a small question. Add an additional "quick answer part" to explain the solution in 2-3 lines

Comment: thanks for the advice !